# control the length a title tooltip is shown

Tags: javascript, html

In IE the tooltip (title attribute) when you hold over an a-tag disappear after a while. Can I somehow control for long it is shown? Or is it up to the browser to decide?

```
<a title="tooltip text">link</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, this is totally up to the browser. You would have to use a custom tooltip script to control this kind of thing.

Comment: @Nick Craver not IE8? It disappears after a few seconds

Comment: @nimo - You are correct, IE does do it different...big surprise?  I guess I try and not have IE itself open for more than a few seconds, so I don't tend to test a tooltip that long either :)

Comment: It used to disappear in Firefox too. Highly annoying. Fixed in 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can imitate it by using a javascript, for instance using jQuery

```
var count = 20000 // Seconds

$(a[title][original-title]).hover(function(){
   $(this).attr('data-title',$(this).attr('title')).attr('title',null); // Transfer to data-title and remove title attrib

},function(){
   $(this).fadeOUt(count,function(){
      //Done
   })
})
```

Now this is just an example of how you can look at things in a different way buut in regards to the the original title popup's length its not possible.

Tipsy Plugin is very good http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/ IMO